# View several comments in one cell on Google Sheets after reopening closed comments

Tags: google-sheets

I added a new comment in Google Sheets, then reopened a closed commend in the same cell. When I click on the cell, I see only one of the two comments. How do I see the other one **in place**?

Answer (score 0):

Don't click on that cell. Click on another cell, then hover your mouse cursor over the cell with comments. The comments will appear overlapping each other. Move your mouse through the cell and through the comments to the comment you're looking for (which might be represented by a small corner). Click on that comment.

[image: visualization of steps]